# How to move rightarrow higher up between Figures?

Tags: positioning, arrows, includegraphics

At the moment I have this code :

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width= 0.4\textwidth]{before}
$\rightarrow$
\includegraphics[width= 0.4\textwidth]{after}
\end{figure}
```

which produces the following :

[image]

Is there some way I can move the rightarrow higher up, between the figures, instead of at the bottom? In particular, I'm wondering if it is possible without redoing my Tikz figures.

Comment: See the `adjustbox` package it can adjust the vertical position of the fixures. Here they all sit on the same base line.

Comment: Also, you can load `graphbox` package and use `\includegraphics[align=<c or m>]{image}`. `graphbox` is lighter than `adjustbox`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Please, always provide MWE, not just code fragment.
- Environment `Figure` is not standard float environment, where you find it or define it?
- See, if the following solution work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % as suggested @daleif in his comment

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.4\textwidth}
\[
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}%{before}
    \longrightarrow
\includegraphics[valign=c]{example-image-duck}%{after}
\]
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is MWE? Also Figure was supposed to be figure, I'll adjust this.

Comment: @J.Shoot see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that